# Record video with HTML input type file capture camcorder from webcam

Tags: html, video, webcam, video-recording

In my company, i had the task to build a website, where users can record a video,
that will be send to the server, some stuff will be done and the user finally gets an email with 
a link to a microsite with that video embedded.

After some research, i came to the conclusion, that it is impossible, at least at the moment,
to capture a video with getUserMedia on iPad.

So the solution is quite simple, i just use a input-element with accept="video/*;capture=camcorder".

```
<input type="file" accept="video/*;capture=camcorder">
```

So far, so good. As I've read on [this](http://www.html5rocks.com/de/tutorials/getusermedia/intro/) page, that it is also possible to capture a video from webcam with this technique, i thought that it is an adequat cross-browser solution.

But after some testing, i can just select an already recorded video on desktop browsers.

Did I misinterprete that article? Or am I just doing it wrong?

Cheers,
Mohammer

Comment: In short `<input accept="video/*` has never been implemented by desktop browsers/OS. See my answer for details & solutions @Mohammer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short you ended up using [`HTML Media Capture` Standard](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-media-capture/) which works by overloading the `<input type="file">` element and adding new values for the `accept` parameter.

**The great thing about it** is that it works great on most mobile browsers (except for recording only the mic on iOS). Support is implemented at least in:

- Safari and Chrome on iOS 6+
- Internet and Chrome on Android 3+

Which pretty much covers anyone, however, depending on the device, you will end up with .mp4 (Android), .mov (iOS) and .3gp files.

**The not so great thing about it is that it defaults to a plain old file selector when used on a desktop OS** instead of opening Photo Booth for example.

Surprisingly the standard's draft included an image of how video capturing through some sort of Photo Booth app would look on a desktop:
[image]

Which is why on the desktop a Flash video recording client + media server is the only solution that works well across browsers and platforms.

There are also commercial solutions including [HDFVR](https://hdfvr.com/) (HTML Media Capture + Flash) and [Pipe](https://addpipe.com/) which does a lot more including the conversion to .mp4, pushing to your S3/FTP and webhooks.

Answer (score 1):

I think that's a typo.

the right way is

```
<p>Capture Video: <input type="file" accept="video/*" id="capture" capture="camcorder">
```

The 'capture' attribute only affects mobile file upload, as far as I know.

source: http://mobilehtml5.org/ts/?id=23

Comment: Actually, I don't think it was a typo, most sites I've found give sample code with `accept="video/*;capture=camcorder"`. But you are correct, the browser doesn't seem to limit the accepted file type correctly unless the capture attribute is separate.

Comment: `capture="camera"`, `capture="camcorder"`, `capture="microphone"` and `capture="filesystem"` were last seen in the [HTML Media Capture draft from July 2012](https://www.w3.org/TR/2012/WD-html-media-capture-20120712/). **Starting with the [December 2012 draft](https://www.w3.org/TR/2012/WD-html-media-capture-20121213/#the-capture-attribute) the `capture` attribute is of type boolean.**